# Backbone.Marionette.Controller throws "Uncaught TypeError: r.apply is not a function"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, typeerror

I want to run my Backbone.Marionette application, but when I try to do it, it breaks in this line of my code (**controller.js**):

```
var appController = new MyController();
```

Where `MyController` looks like:

```
var MyController = new Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({
    showItems: function(options) {
        this.collection = new MyCollection();
        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(options) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                var myView = new MyCollectionView({
                    collection: self.collection
                });
                options.region.show(myView);
            },
            error: function(options) {
                console.log("FAILED");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and it shows the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.apply is not a function
```

If I see the details of this error, it breaks in the `else` of this code from **backbone-min.js** (line 1884).

```
// The constructor function for the new subclass is either defined by you
// (the "constructor" property in your `extend` definition), or defaulted
// by us to simply call the parent constructor.
if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {
  child = protoProps.constructor;
} else {
  child = function(){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); };
}
```

And then, looking at this, you can see that the error starts in my code, as I show in the following image.

[image]

I tried to change the line of my code to this:

```
var appController = MyController();
```

and it shows the same error, but the difference now is that it only breaks in the backbone.js code (same line), which is really weird.

Comment: While in development, you should include the full scripts of the libs you use, they'll have non-minimized error which helps a lot.

Comment: What I meant was to use **backbone.js** instead of **backbone.min.js**.

Comment: Hi Emile, thanks for your reply. I am using the following libraries:

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/3.1.0/backbone.marionette.min.js"></script>

Comment: Remove the `min` like this: `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js`, `http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js`, `http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js`

Comment: Thanks Emile, I followed your instructions but now throws the following error in the backbone.marionette.js code: "backbone.marionette.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks Emile, I followed your instructions but now throws the
>   following error in the backbone.marionette.js code:
>
> ```
> backbone.marionette.js:19 
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined
> ```

The error is easy to spot since it points to the following line in the [Marionette code](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/c1d41d73c60ad117b285fd7495b4c1801ca1873d/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L19):

```
Radio = 'default' in Radio ? Radio['default'] : Radio;
```

Which means `Radio` is undefined.

From [Marionette download page](http://marionettejs.com/download/):

> [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio) is required for Marionette.

Take time to read the documentation on how to get started for each lib you want to use. It will really save you time.

Comment: And that is what I did :)

Comment: Thanks for your several replies Emile. I have read the documentation (even if you think that no, I could solve the Backbone.Radio issue instantly). Now it doesn't seem to recognize the addRegions function when I try to do this:. And i think that it is maybe related with the backbone.marionette version used.

Comment: *this:
var mainApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application;

mainApp.addRegions({
  listRegion: '#listRegion'
});

Comment: @xin use the latest version of each lib if possible.

Answer (score 0):

remove the new key word from the modal, use the new only when you instantiate the modal

```
var MyController = Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({
var appController = new MyController();
```